# Will Java serialization create huge MapEntry array?

Tags: java, arrays, out-of-memory, case-insensitive

I am using Spring jdbc as my persistent layer, and queryForList with default map in the result list. And I can check that the map would be ListOrderedMap decorated CaseInsensitiveMap. In prod env, we got OOM, after checking the dump file, we found a few (around 5) huge CaseInsensitiveMap with large MapEntry array, however, we dive into the data with MAT, found that just 6 entries in the MapEntry array. but the array size is 134217728. All the 5 maps have same size entry array. When reading more details from MAT, we found this is related to ObjectInputStream or java.io.SerialCallbackContext. Is there anybody ever run into such issue when the map is just small but after reading from serialization getting a large entry array?

Comment: Did you notice that 134217728 = 0x8_00_00_00? Suggestive - but I'm not sure of what.

Comment: anyway,doubt how an array could be created or initialized so large without any put actions..

Comment: readObject uses a capacity read (!) from the object input stream to define the array: data = new HashEntry[capacity]; You'd notice 100M puts, and from where would that data come from? Check whether inconsistencies are possible, reduce serialization to just these maps, etc.

Comment: Thank you @laune for your suggestions. I also wonder why there are so many entrys, the capacity should not be that large.